# CSS background-image not visible

Tags: css, background-image

I have tried this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UjhrW/) as its works, i get it anywhere near my webserver and it doesnt work, tried it on three of my sites. Any ideas? *i am using the nasa photo for this question only. 
is there a permission aspect i dont know of? anything please?!?!

I have looked at many questions but nothing is getting me anywhere.

```
.information {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    top: 0;
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 160px;
    background-image:url("http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/743348main_Timelapse_Sun_4k.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:left top;
}
```

Comment: is the real photo hosted on your website?

Comment: Try removing `background-attachment:fixed;`

Comment: bahhhh @3dgoo that worked.... i will never get this time back in my life. why would fixed work on fiddle but not on another?

Comment: Do you have the correct path? Is your image in an images folder or somewhere where you have to traverse the file structure?  '../' or `/images/yourimage.jpg` etc?  If your file isn't in the rout of your server, you are going to need to specify a clear path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `background-attachment:fixed;` from your styling.

[background-attachment: fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)  means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element.

Here is a demo to show you the problem. When the images are lower in the page you cannot see them. As you scroll down you can see the images:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjsc8/)**

**HTML**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!</p>
<div class="information"></div>
<div class="information"></div>
<div class="information"></div>
<div class="information"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum deleniti dolor debitis iste eligendi reprehenderit voluptate dignissimos velit tempora quidem molestias tenetur accusantium ea repellendus atque neque minima quos sed!</p>
```

**CSS**

```css
.information {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; 
    top: 0;
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:left top;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: so my image would have been right at the top of my webpage but not in view to me... interesting. Thank you! Big help.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem accessing this image in jsfiddle so i doubt the issue is to do with permissions.

I think the issue is that your image is too big for the area of the div provided and is just showing the black in the top left of the image.

Try adding `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center center;` to `.information`.

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LjPfH/

Comment: that image was because i didnt want to give my web address. i have now

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't the link use single quotes instead of double quotes in the CSS?

NOT

background-image:url("http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/743348main_Timelapse_Sun_4k.jpg");

TRY

```
 background-image:url('http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/743348main_Timelapse_Sun_4k.jpg');
```

[Updated Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/UjhrW/160/)

[W3 Schools info on background image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: No, it does not matter if you use single quotes, double quote, or no quotes at all.

Comment: The quote don't matter. If you aren't sure, you could google it first.

Comment: Yes it does matter you need to use single quotes in the URL CSS! Look at this fiddle, change the single quotes to double and the background image doesn't appear!  http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/UjhrW/163/

Comment: @user3362232 - you are wrong. If you need to put a question mark in your answer, it's not an answer.

Comment: @user3362232 - No it doesn't matter. Have a look at this demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2ND5d/

Comment: @sheriffderek Then why does it fail on my JS Fiddle?

Comment: So, since your answer is not really an answer, it doesn't serve the community except to possibly confuse people in the future - so I would suggest you remove it, before you keep getting down voted.

Comment: It doesn't fail in your fiddle on my end.

Comment: I've been using double quotes for 5 years. Trust me, They are interchangeable and for good reason. .thing:after { content: ' "quote" '; }

Comment: It's like that in all html, css, and javascript in almost all cases.